# How do I fix the overlapping I have with the aside and article boxes?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my code. my article and aside boxes are overlapping my footer section, any ideas? I also have a problem with making them the same height.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}

.main {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.article {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.aside {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<br>
<div class="main">
  <main>
    <h1>Main</h1>
  </main>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <article>
    <h1>Article</h1>
  </article>
</div>
<br>
<div class="aside">
  <aside>
    <h1>Aside</h1>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to set the position of the two (aside and article) to relative and absolute and fixed but i'm still getting the same problem. None of them have positioned them correctly as they should appear :[image: overlapping problem] Thats what im getting.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `float` for them, so you need to clear the float after, you could use `<div style='clear: both;'/>` after the floated elements like so:

```css
.header {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}

.main {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.article {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.aside {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<br>
<div class="main">
  <main>
    <h1>Main</h1>
  </main>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <article>
    <h1>Article</h1>
  </article>
</div>
<br>
<div class="aside">
  <aside>
    <h1>Aside</h1>
  </aside>
</div>
<div style='clear: both;' />
<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>
</div>
```

My suggestion though, since it's 2022, it's better to use flexbox model for this kind of things.

Comment: +1 I was just explaining this on other question. And not to mention about using `<article>` and `<aside>` tags.

Comment: As I've mentioned in that answer: "The float property will take the elements out of the normal document flow. This could lead to a mess on webpage and it could shift the rest of the elements under the floated elements so they will be partially visible or won’t be visible at all. -> There's solution for that by using clear: both; after floated element(s), but in general better idea is to solve this is by using flexbox"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better for you to use flex instead of float
You can do this

```css
 html {
      margin: 0px;
      width: 100vw;
    }

    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .header {
          background-color: lightskyblue;
          border: 3px solid red;
          height: 200px;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        .content-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: space-between;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        .main {
          background-color: lightskyblue;
          border: 3px solid red;
          height: 200px;
          width: 50%;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .article {
          background-color: lightskyblue;
          border: 3px solid red;
          height: 200px;
          width: 200px;
          margin: 5px;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .aside {
          background-color: lightskyblue;
          border: 3px solid red;
          height: 200px;
          width: 200px;
          margin: 5px;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .footer {
          background-color: lightskyblue;
          border: 3px solid red;
          height: 200px;
          padding: 10px;
          width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <body style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Serif">

      <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="content-container">
      <div class="main">
        <main>
          <h1>Main</h1>
        </main>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
        <article>
          <h1>Article</h1>
        </article>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="aside">
        <aside>
          <h1>Aside</h1>
        </aside>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <footer>
          <h1>Footer</h1>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better for you to use flex instead of float
You can do this

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
}

.main {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.aside {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Serif">

  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="main">
      <main>
        <h1>Main</h1>
      </main>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-content-container">
      <div class="article">
        <article>
          <h1>Article</h1>
        </article>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="aside">
        <aside>
          <h1>Aside</h1>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <footer>
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```